# What's the recommended tech to program Windows shell?

Tags: windows, com, desktop-application

I am developing a small tool that can detecting which folders are being opened in windows explorer and bring it to front if a specific address has been opened.

I can use both C# and C++ and finally pick C# as it is easier than C++ to accomplish the same target. Then I googled the internet and knowing COM object SHDocVw.ShellWindows can help collect all windows being opened. Then I start looking for Microsoft document to see if any functions can help to achieve my other requirements. However, when I search shell related documents: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/windows/desktop/legacy/ff521731(v=vs.85) I am warned that "***We're no longer updating this content regularly. Check the Microsoft Product Lifecycle for information about how this product, service, technology, or API is supported.***" Moreover, some documents even say these techs will be deprecated in Win11 (See the following screenshot)[image]

I am wondering what the status of these Shell related technical. If these are being deprecated. What's the alternative solution? I don't want my tool stop working when start using new Windows. Meanwhile, I am confusing in the study routine of learning Windows desktop technical. Looks like so many technical to achieve the same targets. Is there anyone can give me some road maps?

Last thing, it's really frustrating to search COM object documents at Microsoft sites. Is this tech going down?

Comment: Developing a shell extension in C# can sometimes be problematic because C# COM objects are generally written as in proc DLLs and then there can be collisions with .NET versions. Writing in C++ avoids the problem. There is a regular poster here who wrote a .NET shell extension (or maybe even framework?) in .NET...but I think he used the .NET in an out of process server--to avoid the .NET collision issues.

Answer (score -1):

Microsoft has been trying to kill win32/desktop applications since Windows 8. That parts of the documentation is labeled as "legacy" is not something I would worry too much about. Some of the shell functions have been marked as deprecated for 20 years but still work fine today and too many applications rely on them for Microsoft to successfully remove them.

The Internet Explorer warning is different and IE might actually go away but that does not affect `IShellWindows` which is also used by Explorer.exe and 3rd-party applications. Its implementation lives in a shell DLL and not in IE.